# Why does this code work on a separate file but not inline

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, epub3

This question may seem silly, but I really can't find out what the problem is.  Initially I have a .js file only with this function that adds an audio to the page:

```js
function addAudio(id_name, audio_filepath) {
  var audio = $('<audio />')
                .prop('id', 'audio' + id_name)
                .prop('src', audio_filepath)
                .text("Your reader doesn't support audio.");

  $('body').append(audio);

  $('#' + id_name).click(function () {
    audio.get(0).play();
  });
}
```

And it's being called in the html like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- some content here -->
  <button id="test">Play</button>

  <!-- reference to lib containing jquery -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib.min.js"></script>

  <!-- script where the function addAudio resides -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/add-audio.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function() {
      addAudio('test', 'audio/01-test.wav');
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And that works fine. The problem is when I try to move the function out of the file and put it inline in the script tag. In that case, when I click the button, the console prints `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined`.

This is the modified code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- some content here -->
  <button id="test">Play</button>

  <!-- reference to lib containing jquery -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function addAudio(id_name, audio_filepath) {
      var audio = $('<audio />')
                    .prop('id', 'audio' + id_name)
                    .prop('src', audio_filepath)
                    .text("Your reader doesn't support audio.");

      $('body').append(audio);

      $('#' + id_name).click(function () {
        audio.get(0).play();
      });
    }

    $().ready(function() {
      addAudio('test', 'audio/01-test.wav');
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Trying to isolate the error, I found out that when the function is in the .js file, the variable `audio` is a jquery object `[audio#audiotest]`, but when the function is inline, that variable is the object `n.fn.init {}`.

Why does that happen?

**EDIT**

I've noticed that that happens because it's in a **xhtml** file (I'm making an ebook in epub3 format). If I change the file to **html** it works again. But that is odd, because audio tags are supported in xhtml (you can check the specification here: http://www.idpf.org/accessibility/guidelines/content/xhtml/audio.php), and like I said, it works if the function is in a separate file. So why inline does not?

Comment: what does it show in your browser console?

Comment: When the code is in the separate file the audio gets played normally. When the code is inline the console says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined`

Comment: There is on `<button id="test">Play</button>` in the second one...

Comment: ok, just a guess, but I think the url of the audio might require modification when you are calling it from inline script as your external script is in another folder and not same level as the html file.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan I fixed the question. Thank you.

Comment: @Mike, the url is ok. I've tried to use both files on same level too and no success :( .

Comment: What I find odd is that in the js file `console.log(audio)` prints an audio object, but when in inline script, it prints `n.fn.init {}`

Comment: When exactly do you get the error? When you click the button or on page load/render?

Comment: I only get the error when I click the button.

Comment: I edited the question, I hope it's clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, people. Thank you all for your attention and help, and sorry for the inconvenience. I was thinking about deleting this question, but I'm going to answer it to help those who might pass through the same thing.

According to Mozilla Foundation, using inline javascript in XHTML is troublesome: (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/Properly_Using_CSS_and_JavaScript_in_XHTML_Documents_/Examples#Example_1)

> JavaScript typically contains characters which can not exist in XHTML outside of CDATA Sections.

So I solved the problem changing the line `$('<audio />')` to `$('&t;audio /gt;')`

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with your file reference. When I put your code into jsfiddle it appears to work referencing a wav file on the internet.

https://jsfiddle.net/ur64L8uh/

```
    function addAudio(id_name, audio_filepath) {
      var audio = $('<audio />')
                    .prop('id', 'audio' + id_name)
                    .prop('src', audio_filepath)
                    .text("Your reader doesn't support audio.");

      $('body').append(audio);

      $('#' + id_name).click(function () {
        audio.get(0).play();
      });
    }

    $().ready(function() {
      addAudio('test', 'http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/WAV/Media-Convert/Media-Convert_test1_Alaw_Mono_VBR_8SS_16000Hz.wav');
    });
}
```

Comment: I've tried to change the url to the one you provided, but still no success.